# Is there a simple function, where I input 1 and it outputs 0, and if I input 0 it outputs 1?

Tags: calculus

I am programming php, and I don't want to use IFs or booleans for this, can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What about $1-x$?

Comment: $x \rightarrow 1-x$

Comment: That actualy works, thanks you! I dont know how i didn't think of that before...

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use the bitwise operator `~$x & 1`